# LINQ query for specific group

Tags: sql, linq

I have a data list that looks like below.

```
GroupId   Color
---------
1        Blue
1        Red
2        Green
2        Blue
3        White
3        Red
3        Yellow
4        Blue
4        Red
```

I am trying to write a LINQ query that can be used to filter this set in such a way that it can provide answer to following question(s).

Give me group(s) where color is Blue and Red.
Answer to this question will be a list with group Id 1 and 4.

The answer will not contain 2 even though it has blue color in it. The match needs to be exact on blue and red.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what works as generic solution.

```
var checkColors = new[] { "Blue", "Red" };

var gp = from d in definitions
         group d by d.GroupId
         into g
         let colorNames = g.Select(dim => dim.Color)
         where g.Any(gd => !checkColors.Except(colorNames).Any())
         select g.Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var result = list.GroupBy(item => item.GroupdId)
            .Where(x=>x.All(y=>y.Color=="Blue" || y.Color=="Red")).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList();
```

This should return the answer you want.

Group the items by groupid first and then find all the groups that contain "Blue" or "Red" only, then return the group id in a list.

Comment: This will fail if gorup is having one extra color other than Blue or Red